# including php inside jquery and loop with different id inside jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, loops

iam currently doing a php code that creates different 'id' attribute for each row. i want to assign each row a same jquery code that do process for that particular row.

for instance let
         
as first row
              
as second row
... so on

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#brand').change(function(){  
var brand_id = $(this).val(); 
 $.ajax({  
 url:"load_data.php", 
method:"POST", 
data:{brand_id:brand_id},
success:function(data){  
$('#kg').html(data);
 }  
 });  
});
```

});

```
$(document).on("change","#kg,#Quantity",function()
{
valuemath = value * $("#kg").val();
 var value = $("#Quantity").val(),
$("#dom_element").text(valuemath);
});
```

How can i loop kg,brand,quantity,dom_element in this code? because if i put same id name for every row like     then corresponding row's(event) value not changing...

i tried

```
static $brandi =1000;

static $kgi = 2000;

static $Quantityi = 3000;

static $dom_elementi = 4000;

----start loop

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $('#'<?php echo $brandi; ?>'').change(function(){ 
var brand_id = $(this).val();  
 $.ajax({ 
url:"load_data.php",  
 method:"POST", 
data:{brand_id:brand_id},
success:function(data){

$('#'<?php echo $kgi; ?>'').html(data);
 }  

 });    
}); 

$(document).on("change","#"<?php echo $kgi; ?>",#"<?php echo $Quantityi; ?>"",function()
{
var value = $("#"<?php echo $Quantityi; ?>"").val(),
valuemath = value * $("#"<?php echo $kgi; ?>"").val();
$("#"<?php echo $dom_elementi; ?>"").text(valuemath);
});

</script>

$brandi++;
$kgi++;
$Quantityi++;
$dom_elementi++;

--- go to start of loop
```

but this method didnt worked...

Comment: What if you give all your rows a common `class` attribute and then add a single handler to all the rows that have that class?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, it sounds like you should be using a class for what you're doing. Second of all, based on the code you tried, you have JavaScript syntax errors. Your quotes are not correct. For example, what you have now:

```
$('#'<?php echo $kgi; ?>'').html(data);
```

should actually be:

```
$('#<?php echo $kgi; ?>').html(data);
```

and:

```
$(document).on("change","#"<?php echo $kgi; ?>",#"<?php echo $Quantityi; ?>"",function()
```

should be:

```
$(document).on("change","#<?php echo $kgi; ?>","#<?php echo $Quantityi; ?>",function()
```

You repeat this pattern through out your script, so you don't actually know that what you have doesn't work because your syntax is wrong. If you fix your syntax, it might work (but likely a class approach will still be better).